# Marshal to std::string from System::String^ member of struct handle

Tags: .net, c++-cli, marshalling

I am trying to marshal to a std::string from a System::String^.

Usually this can be done with the `marshal_as<T>` template i.e.

```
System::String ^managedString = "test";
std::string stdString = marshal_as<std::string>(managedString);
```

But if the String^ is part of a struct that is accessed by reference i.e.

```
value struct SomeStruct {
    String ^managedString;
};

auto structHandle = gcnew SomeStruct();
structHandle->managedString = "test";
std::string stdString = marshal_as<std::string>(structHandle->managedString);
```

The compiler will throw the following error

> error C2665: 'msclr::interop::marshal_as' : none of the 3 overloads
>   could convert all the argument types

However if the struct is not a handle, but the actual struct, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   auto structHandle = gcnew SomeStruct();
```

This is where the problem started.  The *structHandle* reference points to a *boxed* copy of SomeStruct.  It needs to be boxed because SomeStruct is a value type, the copy of the struct is stored on the GC heap.

The signature of the marshal_as<> overload you are trying to use is:

```
   marshal_as<std::string,System::String^>(System::String ^const &)
```

The `const&` is the problem, you cannot get an unmanaged reference to the member, its address is not stable (not const) since the garbage collector can move the object while marshal_as<> is executing.  That would cause disaster when marshal_as now dereferences an object that's no longer there.

A workaround is to copy the reference out of the boxed object before you try to convert it:

```
   structHandle->managedString = "test";
   String^ refCopy = structHandle->managedString;
   std::string stdString = marshal_as<std::string>(refCopy);   // fine
```

But that's just a hack around the real problem in your code.  Value types exist to make code efficient, allowing structures to be stored on the stack frame or a CPU register.  Just like a native C++ object.  You are throwing that advantage away by boxing the struct.  Or in other words, there just wasn't any point in declaring a `value struct` if you are not going to treat it as a value.  Use it properly for the correct fix:

```
    SomeStruct value;
    value.managedString = "test";
    auto result = marshal_as<std::string>(value.managedString);  // fine
```

Or if you got the reference by mistakenly using ^ on a function argument then rewrite to:

```
    void SomeFunction(SomeStruct% arg) {
        auto nativeString = marshal_as<std::string>(arg.managedString);
        '' etc..
    }
```

Note the use of % instead of ^ to pass a variable by reference.  But don't do that, the point of a value type is that it is cheaper to copy the value than having to dereference a pointer to obtain the value.  Make sure your value type is not too big, it should not have more than 4 fields.  If it is bigger then you should use a reference type.

Comment: I have to admit the above example was dumped down a bit. The reason for it being a handle is that the struct access and marshalling appears in a function which is passed a reference to a struct containing 6 String^. Would it be faster to pass in the struct as a copy rather than pass a reference?

Comment: Hmya, you are probably doing that wrong as well.  You pass a reference to a variable with %, not ^.  But the point of a value type is to pass it by value.  There's simple guidance to decide if you want a value type or a reference type.  6 fields is too many, copying values is only efficient when the value type has 4 fields or less.  Use a `ref struct` or `ref class` here.

Comment: Would this not be dependent on how many times members are accessed? I would imagine the cost incurred by dereferencing the pointer many times will surpass the cost incurred by copying at some point?

Comment: The point of a value type is that there is no pointer dereference.   When the value gets too large (more than 4 fields) then it cannot easily be passed by value anymore and a pointer to value is passed.  So you're not ahead anymore.

Comment: What is the difference between `void SomeFunction(SomeStruct ^arg); SomeFunction(%value)` and `void SomeFunction(SomeStruct %arg); SomeFunction(value)`?

Comment: The first one should only ever be used if *arg* is a reference type.  The second passes a reference to a variable, regardless of its type, only use it if you intend to have changes to *value* be passed back to the caller.

Comment: How would switching to a `ref` type work? The `ref` type would be heap allocated and thus it would not be possible to marshal the members of the `ref` type?

Comment: No idea what you mean, you only talked about marshaling a string.  That's not a problem.  Click the Ask Question button when you have more questions.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but I think you should rather think in terms of `sizeof` instead of field count. If you have 4 `System::Guid` fields it's not the same thing as 4 `char` fields.

Comment: No, what matters is that the value can be stored in CPU registers.  You can only count on having 4 uncommitted registers available in the x86 jitter.  That advice is getting a bit dated, albeit that compiling C++/CLI to 32-bit is still very common, there are more in x64.

Comment: I mean a `System::Guid` is 128 bits, so it can't fit in a CPU register anyway. Do you think the x64 JIT would split such a value across two registers to pass it around? That'd be interesting, but I'd rather expect it to just put it on the stack frame and use it from there.

Comment: System::Guid is a struct.  Same rules apply, the combination will have well over 4 fields.